# Create string from HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, tostring

What I would like to be able to do is create a string from a Javascript HTMLElement Object. For example:

```
var day = document.createElement("div");
day.className = "day";
day.textContent = "Random Text";
```

Now we have create the `day` HTMLDivElement Object is it possible to make it print as a string? e.g.

```
<div class="day">Random Text</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Variant on Gump's wrapper, since his implementation lifts the target node out of the document.

```
function nodeToString ( node ) {
   var tmpNode = document.createElement( "div" );
   tmpNode.appendChild( node.cloneNode( true ) );
   var str = tmpNode.innerHTML;
   tmpNode = node = null; // prevent memory leaks in IE
   return str;
}
```

To print the resulting string on screen (re: escaped)

```
var escapedStr = nodeToString( node ).replace( "<" , "&lt;" ).replace( ">" , "&gt;");
outputNode.innerHTML += escapedStr;
```

Note, attributes like "class" , "id" , etc being stringified properly is questionable.

Comment: Simple yet effective, just what i was looking for. Its a pity the outerHTML method is not supported by Firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can use this function (taken from pure.js)

```
function outerHTML(node){
 return node.outerHTML || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A few years have passed since the last answers. So here is an easier approach:
I found out that [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) is supported by all major browsers now (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=outerhtml)).
You can use it to get the HTML of an JS element with ease:

```
// Create a sample HTMLDivElement
var Day = document.createElement("div");
Day.className = "day";
Day.textContent = "Random Text";

// Log the element's HTML to the console
console.log(Day.outerHTML)
```

This will log: `<div class="day">Random Text</div>`

Comment: outerHTML ! Of course ! Sir you are a genius

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap that element into another element and use `innerHTML` on it:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.appendChild(day);
var str = wrapper.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create text node to add text for your created element like this:

```
var day = document.createElement("div");
day.className = "day";
// create text node
var txt = document.createTextNode('Random Text');
// add text to div now
day.appendChild(txt);
// append to body
document.body.appendChild(day);
```

Answer (score 2):

My element was a object with `element : HTMLDivElement`, so this worked for me.

```
console.log(row.element.outerHTML);
```

If you have just `HTMLDivElement`, then this should work:

```
console.log(row.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use `createElement` if you can also directly parse a string?
Like: `var string = '<div class="' + class + '">' + text + '</div>';`

Comment: Plenty of reasons why op might need to do this...as I do.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the function **outerHTML**

```
var anc = document.createElement("a");
anc.href = "https://developer.mozilla.org?a=b&c=d";
console.log(anc.outerHTML); // output: "<a href='https://developer.mozilla.org?a=b&amp;c=d'></a>"
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)