# Converting DOM elements back into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am creating a script to rearrange `<div>` elements on a page. It can get them into an array, but that array's contents look like:

`[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],`

None of the following have worked:

`my_array.innerHTML`

`my_array.outerHTML`

`my_array.html`

`my_array.toString()`

So how can I get this array back into something that looks like:
`<div class="rect red"></div><div class="rect green"></div><div class="rect blue"></div><div class="rect yellow"></div>`, and have that render as divs on the page?

Here is the full code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.rect {width:24px; height:12px; border-radius:12px; border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25); margin-bottom:12px}
.red {background-color:#c21}
.green {background-color:#1c3}
.blue {background-color:#28f}
.yellow {background-color:#ed1}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target">
 <div class="rect red"></div>
 <div class="rect green"></div>
 <div class="rect blue"></div>
 <div class="rect yellow"></div>
</div>
<script>
function move_before(arr, ndx){ //move the element one place earlier in the array
 var move = arr[ndx];
 arr.splice(ndx, 1); //from index #'ndx', remove 1 element
 arr.splice(ndx-1, 0, move); //from the index before #'ndx', remove 0 elements, then insert the value of 'move'
}

$(".rect").click( function() { // rearrange the order of divs when one is clicked
 var sort = Array.from( $(this).parent().children() );
 var current_index = $(this).index();

 move_before(sort, current_index); // put each element into a new array
 var i = 0;
 var updated_arr = [];
 while (i <= sort.length) {
  updated_arr.push(sort[i]);
  i = i+1;
 }
 document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = updated_arr;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239587/create-string-from-htmldivelement

Comment: You have to call `outerHTML` on the array elements, not the array.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. When I try `my_array[i].html` or similar things (like outer and inner) I get `TypeError: my_array[i] is undefined` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: @Barmar Done.  :-)

Comment: Change `i <= sort.length` to `i < sort.length`. Why do so many people get this wrong?

Comment: Okay, I did that. But now instead of an error I just get `,,,`. I was actually on the fence about that, and tried `<` instead of `<=` once before, but the result of `,,,` was equally useless as the error, so I dismissed it. (I think a lot of people get it wrong because they worry that the last array element might not get counted without the `=` and don't pause to consider that arrays start from 0.) So now I can see that `sort[i].outerHTML` is working, except that I need to get rid of the resulting commas - and more importantly, figure out why the click isn't working the second time through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `appendChild()`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.rect {width:24px; height:12px; border-radius:12px; border:4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25); margin-bottom:12px}
.red {background-color:#c21}
.green {background-color:#1c3}
.blue {background-color:#28f}
.yellow {background-color:#ed1}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target">
 <div class="rect red"></div>
 <div class="rect green"></div>
 <div class="rect blue"></div>
 <div class="rect yellow"></div>
</div>
<script>
function move_before(arr, ndx){ //move the element one place earlier in the array
 var move = arr[ndx];
 arr.splice(ndx, 1); //from index #'ndx', remove 1 element
 arr.splice(ndx-1, 0, move); //from the index before #'ndx', remove 0 elements, then insert the value of 'move'
}

$(".rect").click( function() { // rearrange the order of divs when one is clicked
 var sort = Array.from( $(this).parent().children() );
 var current_index = $(this).index();

 move_before(sort, current_index); // put each element into a new array
 var i = 0;
 var updated_arr = [];
 while (i <= sort.length) {
  updated_arr.push(sort[i]);
  i = i+1;
 }
  for(i=0;i<updated_arr.length-1;i++){
 document.getElementById("target").appendChild(updated_arr[i]);
   }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is similar to:

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
console.log(div);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two minor changes to make it work:

1. use `<` instead of `=<` in the loop to avoid one extra iteration.
2. Use `Element.appendChild()` to add elements in a Node. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Great job on using `this`!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .rect {
        width: 24px;
        height: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }
      .red {
        background-color: #c21;
      }
      .green {
        background-color: #1c3;
      }
      .blue {
        background-color: #28f;
      }
      .yellow {
        background-color: #ed1;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target">
      <div class="rect red"></div>
      <div class="rect green"></div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>
      <div class="rect yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function move_before(arr, ndx) {
        //move the element one place earlier in the array
        var move = arr[ndx];
        arr.splice(ndx, 1); //from index #'ndx', remove 1 element
        arr.splice(ndx - 1, 0, move); //from the index before #'ndx', remove 0 elements, then insert the value of 'move'
      }

      $(".rect").click(function() {
        // rearrange the order of divs when one is clicked
        var sort = Array.from(
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .children()
        );
        var current_index = $(this).index();

        move_before(sort, current_index); // put each element into a new array
        var i = 0;
        var updated_arr = [];
        while (i <= sort.length) {
          updated_arr.push(sort[i]);
          i = i + 1;
        }
        updated_arr.map(element =>
          document.getElementById("target").appendChild(element)
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create the `updated_arr`. Just join the `outerHTML` of the `HTMLElement` objects in `sort` array.

`move_before(sort, current_index);
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = sort.map(elem => elem.outerHTML).join('');`

Also update your event binding to
`$("#target").bind('click', '.rect', function() { ...... });`